# Automatically change node numbers after deleting a node in Firebase Realtime Database Array

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I have a Firebase Realtime Database structured as shown above ^^

However, when I delete a node. Let's say I delete node number 7 then the structure has not '7' in it!!
But when I EXPORT the JSON data, it looks like an array:

```
"nodeName": [ {
    "name": 'firstUser'
  }, {
    "name": 'secondUser'
  }
]
```

and when I IMPORT the same JSON again, the numbers of NODE gets adjusted automatically! Let's say we had 56 nodes earlier and after deleting a node we had 55 but number '7' was missing.

After importing now we see 55 nodes and there is number 7 NODE!!

The questions is, how do I automatically change  number of nodes below [that is subtract 1] after a node is deleted and without exporting n re-importing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do I automatically change number of nodes below [that is subtract 1] after a node is deleted and without exporting n re-importing

You can't change the name of a node.  What you can do is read the node, then write it back with a new name.

In general, what you're trying to do here isn't a good idea with Firebase Realtime Database.  [Indexed arrays are a poor choice](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html) for modeling NoSQL data.  Definitely read that post.

If you want to add data to a list, the recommended approach is to [push() data into the list](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#section-ways-to-save).  If you require a sort order for the list, you should use a child value in each node, and [sort the list by that field](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#ordering-by-a-specified-child-key).